# Angular2 Route Configuration: Child Routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, children

I'm having a little trouble with the route configuration in my project and hoping someone could provide some insight.  I'm currently in Angular2 RC6 using @angular/router 3.0.0-rc2.

I have an application which renders a list and a profile page for details.  The list and the profile have their views displayed in the default `<router-outlet>`.  You initially see the list, click an item in it, and then are shown the profile. Within the profile html template, there's another `<router-outlet name="profile">` which I'd like for sections of the profile to render into.
Currently, I'm getting an error with my below configuration when I try to navigate to the profile's first section:

`this.router.navigateByUrl("/edit/" + id + "(profile:basic)");`

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'basic'(…)`

I've declared it in the route configuration below but I'm obviously doing something incorrectly.

**Route Configuration**

```
 [
    {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: ClientProfile,
        children: [
           { path: '', redirectTo: 'basic', pathMatch: "full" },
           { path: 'basic', component: BasicInfo, outlet: "profile" },
            { path: 'people', component: ManagePersons, outlet: "profile" }
        ]
    },
    { path: '', component: ClientList },
    { path: '**', component: ClientList }
];
```

**General HTML Structure**

```
<app>
 <router-outlet>
    <client-list></client-list>
    <client-profile> 
      <ul class='nav'>...</ul>
      <router-outlet name="profile"></router-outlet>
    </client-profile>
  </router-outlet>
</app>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**Update 1**
Changing the route configuration to the below allowed me to access the profile page correctly.  But now I can't seem to navigate to the people section of the profile.

```
[
     {
        path: 'edit/:id',
        component: ClientProfile,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: BasicInfo, outlet: "profile" },
            { path: 'people', component: ManagePersons, outlet: "profile" }
        ]
    },
    { path: '', component: ClientList },
    { path: '**', component: ClientList }
];
```